# Почему не работает экран arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Использую Arduino Due и цветной графический дисплей 2.8 TFT 320x240. 
Код:

```
#include <UTFT.h>                              // подключаем библиотеку UTFT
UTFT myGLCD(TFT01_24SP,11,12,3,2,5);             // объявляем объект myGLCD класса библиотеки UTFT указывая тип дисплея TFT01_24SP и номера выводов Arduino к которым подключён дисплей: SDI/MOSI, SCK, CS, RESET, DC/RS. Можно использовать любые выводы Arduino.
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];                    // подключаем маленький шрифт
extern uint8_t BigFont[];                      // подключаем большой шрифт
extern uint8_t SevenSegNumFont[];              // подключаем шрифт имитирующий семисегментный индикатор
                                               //
void setup(){                                  //
   myGLCD.InitLCD();
    pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
   pinMode(6, OUTPUT);  // инициализируем цифровой контакт 6 на работу на вывод данных
                   // инициируем дисплей
}                                              //
                                               //
void loop(){ 
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);  // подаем на контакт 6 напряжение высокого уровня — включаем светодиод
                                        //
   myGLCD.clrScr();   
   delay(5000);                         // стираем всю информацию с дисплея
   myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);                    // устанавливаем большой шрифт
   myGLCD.setColor(VGA_BLUE);                  // устанавливаем синий цвет текста
   myGLCD.print("BigFont", CENTER, 100);       // выводим текст на дисплей (выравнивание по ширине - центр дисплея, координата по высоте 100 точек)
   myGLCD.print("iarduino.ru", CENTER, 115);   // выводим текст на дисплей (выравнивание по ширине - центр дисплея, координата по высоте 115 точек)
                                               //
 delay(5000);                               // ждём 20 секунд
 digitalWrite(6, LOW);
 delay(5000);  
}
```

Экран подключаю к тем пинам, что указаны в коде напрямую. 
При этом работает только подсветка, гаснет и загорается согласно скрипту.
 Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Язык скорее похож на С++. ¿Что такое `BigFont`? ¿Оно там реально загружается?

Comment: Это стандартный шрифт библиотеки UTFT